# Relationship Find Misunderstanding

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, methods

Maybe I am overlooking something obvious but I'm trying to apply a practical scenario to this rails for Zombies tutorial.

--------Question------------
Assuming the models and relationships are properly defined, find all the weapons that belong to Zombie 'Ash'.

```
class Zombie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :weapons
end

class Weapon < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :zombie
end
```

The tutorial accepts the answer of-

```
z = Zombie.find(1)
[#<Zombie ­id: 1, nam­e: "Ash", ­graveyard:­ "Glen Hav­en Memoria­l Cemetery­">]

z.weapons
[#<Weapon ­id: 1, nam­e: "Hammer­", strengt­h: 1, zomb­ie_id: 1>]
```

but for me that is not so practical, as if I were working on the project and that type of question came up I would do this.

```
ash = Zombie.where(:name => "Ash")
[#<Zombie ­id: 1, nam­e: "Ash", ­graveyard:­ "Glen Hav­en Memoria­l Cemetery­">]
```

But

```
ash.weapons
```

gives the output

```
#<NoMetho­dError: un­defined me­thod `weap­ons' for #­<ActiveR­ecord::Rel­ation:0x00­0000163347­38>>
```

How can this be when the output for finding the zombie is exactly the same and the way I found the zombie is much more practical given the way the question is framed (even though they provide db tables). Could it be a nuance with the codeschool interactive console or am I missing something?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your result shows itself:

```
[#<Zombie ­id: 1, nam­e: "Ash", ­graveyard:­ "Glen Hav­en Memoria­l Cemetery­">]
```

This is some sort of beefed up array.
so if you would do:

```
ash = Zombie.where(:name => "Ash").first
ash.weapons
```

will return all the weapons.

Comment: Still not sure I understand as both arrays are indentically 'beefed' up yet one responds differently to the weapons call. I guess my larger question is could/would I used what I thought to be a practical call in practice?

Comment: when you do find(1) it will return a single resource. where will return an active record relation. if you do ash.class in both cases you will see that they are two different things